# Calculating the summation of powers of a number modulo a number

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are 3 numbers: `T, N, M. 1 ≤ T, M ≤ 10^9, 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^18` .

What is asked in the problem is to compute `[Σ(T^i)]mod(m)` where i varies from 0 to n. Obviously, O(N) or O(M) solutions wouldn't work because of 1 second time limit. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in previous answers, you may use the formula for geometric progression sum. However there is a small problem - if m is not prime, computing `(T^n - 1) / (T - 1)` can not be done directly - the division will not be a well-defined operations. In fact there is a solution that can handle even non prime modules and will have a complexity `O(log(n) * log(n))`. The approach is similar to binary exponentiation. Here is my code written in c++ for this(note that my solution uses binary exponentiation internally):

```
typedef long long ll;
ll binary_exponent(ll x, ll y, ll mod) {
  ll res = 1; 
  ll p = x; 
  while (y) {
    if (y % 2) { 
      res = (res * p) % mod; 
    }    
    p = (p * p) % mod; 
    y /= 2;
  }
  return res; 
}

ll gp_sum(ll a, int n, ll mod) {
  ll A = 1; 
  int num = 0; 
  ll res = 0; 
  ll degree = 1; 
  while (n) {
    if (n & (1 << num)) {
      n &= (~(1 << num));
      res = (res + (A * binary_exponent(a, n, mod)) % mod) % mod; 
    }    
    A = (A + (A * binary_exponent(a, degree, mod)) % mod) % mod; 
    degree *= 2;
    num++;
  }
  return res; 
}
```

In this solution `A` stores consecutively the values `1`, `1 + a`, `1 + a + a^2 + a^3`, ...`1 + a + a^2 + ... a ^ (2^n - 1)`.

Also just like in binary exponentiation if I want to compute the sum of `n` degrees of `a`, I split `n` to sum of powers of two(essentially using the binary representation of `n`). Now having the above sequence of values for `A`, I choose the appropriate lengths(the ones that correspond to `1` bits of the binary representation of `n`) and multiply the sum by some value of `a` accumulating the result in `res`. Computing the values of `A` will take `O(log(n))` time and for each value I may have to compute a degree of `a` which will result in another `O(log(n))` - thus overall we have `O(log(n) * log (n))`.

Let's take an example - we want to compute `1 + a + a^2 .... + a ^ 10`. In this case, we call `gp_sum(a, 11, mod)`.

On the first iteration `n & (1 << 0)` is not zero as the first bit of 11(`1011(2)`) is 1. Thus I turn off this bit setting n to `10` and I accumulate in res: `0 + 1 * (a ^ (10))` = `a^10`. A is now `a + 1`.

The next second bit is also set in 10(`1010(2)`), so now n becomes `8` and `res` is `a^10 + (a + 1)*(a^8)`=`a^10 + a^9 + a^8`. A is now `1 + a + a^2 + a^3`

Next bit is 0, thus res stays the same, but A will become `1 + a + a^2 + ... a^7`.

On the last iteration the bit is 1 so we have:
`res = a^10 + a^9 + a^8 + a^0 *(1 + a + a^2 + ... +a^7)` = `1 + a .... + a ^10`.

Answer (score 0):

One can use an algorithm which is similar to binary exponentiation:

```
// Returns a pair <t^n mod m, sum of t^0..t^n mod m>,
// I assume that int is big enough to hold all values without overflowing. 
pair<int, int> calc(int t, int n, int m) 
    if n == 0 // Base case. t^0 is always 1.
        return (1 % m, 1 % m)
    if n % 2 == 1
        // We just compute the result for n - 1 and then add t^n.
        (prevPow, prevSum) = calc(t, n - 1, m)
        curPow = prevPow * t % m
        curSum = (prevSum + curPow) % m
        return (curPow, curSum)
    // If n is even, we compute the sum for the first half.
    (halfPow, halfSum) = calc(t, n / 2, m)
    curPow = halfPow * halfPow % m // t^n = (t^(n/2))^2
    curSum = (halfSum * halfPow + halfSum) % m 
    return (curPow, curSum)
```

The time complexity is `O(log n)`(the analysis is the same as for the binary exponentiation algorithm). Why is it better than a closed form formula for geometric progression? The latter involves division by `(t - 1)`. But it is not guaranteed that there is an inverse of `t - 1` mod `m`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```
a^1 + a^2 + ... + a^n = a(1-a^n) / (1-a)
```

so, you just need to calc:

```
a  * (1 - a^n) / (1 - a) mod M
```

and you can find O(logN) way to calc a^n mod M

Answer (score -2):

It's a geometric series whose sum is equal to :

[image]

Comment: What if there is no inverse element of `1  - r` mod `m`?

Comment: Calculate the hole thing, use `BigInteger` then do it mod `m`

Comment: It is not possible in practice. The sum of `(10^9)^i` for `i = 0 ... 10^18` is way too big.

Comment: It is not `(10^9)^18`. It is `(10^9)^(10^18)`.